# Is theoretical Linear Algebra still an active field of research?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, education

Numerical Linear Algebra seems to be a very active area right now, but is there any work still being done on the purely theoretical side?

To put it another way...is it possible for someone to write a book titled "All of Linear Algebra" and actually create a closed set of concepts that encompass this field?

For example, I'm thinking a book like Peter Lax's Linear Algebra and its Applications seems to be close to this, but a lot of reviewers of the book stated it was a *select* group of topics.

Comment: I think nowadays its not called "linear algebra" (the uncool name) its called "non-commutative ring theory" (the cool name). But the most important examples of non-commutative rings tend to be matrix rings, so non-commutative ring theory could reasonably be viewed as the modern-day version of theoretical linear algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched MathSciNet.  Classification 15 is "Linear and multilinear algebra; matrix theory".
There are (so far) more than 400 papers dated 2015 with that classification.

**a few examples**

Hora, Jan; Pudlák, Petr; Classification of 8-dimensional Trilinear Alternating Forms over GF(2). Comm. Algebra 43 (2015), no. 8, 3459–3471.

Farber, Miriam; Berman, Abraham; A contribution to the connections between Fibonacci numbers and matrix theory. Involve 8 (2015), no. 3, 491–501.

Bu, Changjiang; Wei, Yuanpeng; Sun, Lizhu; Zhou, Jiang; Brualdi-type eigenvalue inclusion sets of tensors. Linear Algebra Appl. 480 (2015), 168–175.

Comment: Thanks, but are a lot of those theoretical research into numerical linear algebraic methods?

Comment: 65F is numerical linear algebra.  But I guess is is possible that some of those with primary classification 15 were incorrectly classified.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification...i'd check myself if it weren't a subscription service. Perhaps Ill try ArXiv as well, see what's coming up.

Comment: Thanks, these are great. Looks like @goblin comment holds as well...its now titled "non-commutative yadda yadda". Much like my job...used to be "mathematical statistician" now its "Data Scientist" ;-)